# Create a single Swift Package that includes two or more `target`s

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

We have designed a Swift Package that includes MapKit Extensions and some custom `func`s that perform some Geographic computations.  The intended usage would be to use a single Swift Package imported into Xcode to use two classes:  one custom and the other extensions to `MKMapView`.

Is it possible to create a single Swift Package that includes two or more `target`s?  How to properly update `Package.swift` to support multiple targets?

```
import MapKitSwiftExtensions
import CustomGeospatialComputations
```

---

The impression is that a second `target` in `Package.swift` can be added in the `targets` array.

```
.library(
  name: "MapKit Swift Extensions", 
  targets: ["MapKitSwiftExtensions", "CustomGeospatialComputations"]
)
```

But when `CustomGeospatialComputations` is added to the `targets` array, I get this error :

> *target 'CustomGeospatialComputations' referenced in product 'MapKit Swift Extensions' could not be found*

---

Ideally, I would like to have this file structure for development.

```
.
├── Package.swift
├── README.md
├── Sources
│   └── CustomGeospatialComputations
│       └── GeoComputations.swift
│   └── MapKitSwiftExtensions
│       └── MKMapView+Extensions.swift
```

This is the `Package.swift` that works (without `CustomGeospatialComputations`)

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MapKit Swift Extensions",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MapKit Swift Extensions"],
            targets: ["MapboxSwiftExtensions"),
    ],
    dependencies: [ ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MapKitSwiftExtensions",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

Comment: When you add `CustomGeospatialComputations` to your library product, do you also add the corresponding `CustomGeospatialComputations` target to your `targets` array?

Comment: How is defined `CustomGeospatialComputations` when set?  Alongside `.target(name: "MapKitSwiftExtensions", dependencies: [])` too? Could you show the full Package.swift when that's the case?

Comment: @larme — I was only adjusting `.library(..., targets: ["MapKitSwiftExtensions", "CustomGeospatialComputations"]`.  Which the answer below shows I was only doing half the proper configuration.

Comment: A little tip, when I "add" a thing, I check where the other item at the same level are doing. Here `targets: ["MapKitSwiftExtensions", "CustomGeospatialComputations"]`, you added `CustomGeospatialComputations`, so it needed the same treatment as the previous one one the same level `MapKitSwiftExtensions`. So also a `targets`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error message, I'm pretty sure you're forgetting to define the `CustomGeospatialComputations` target in your manifest's `targets` array. Your complete manifest should look like this:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MapKit Swift Extensions",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MapKit Swift Extensions",

            // Add the targets to your product.
            targets: ["MapKitSwiftExtensions", "CustomGeospatialComputations"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [ ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MapKitSwiftExtensions",
            dependencies: []),

        // Define the target for the package.
        .target(
            name: "CustomGeospatialComputations",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Caleb Kleveter - that was the difference!  Now there are no errors in the Xcode "Resolve Swift Packages" step.  Your comments in your Package.swift were useful as well.